# Plt.Error Upper Limits Have Tail End of Arrow Point At My Coordinate

Tags: matplotlib, plot, errorbar

For two days I've been trying to solve this problem.
I'm plotting upper limits, so I need downward pointing arrows to point at my points. Among other things, I've now tried using Plt.Error to get these arrows. The problem is, the tail end of the arrow points at the point and not the tip.

Below, I show my code for plotting this data leaving out the portion where I read in the data. In addition, I've added two images. The first image is the resulting plot. The second image is of the yellow arrow in that plot that is referring to the point (10,.0076) where you can clearly see the tail end of the arrow is point at that coordinate.

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pylab

```
f1 = plt.figure(0)
plt.errorbar(days,fluxdensity,yerr=0.01,uplims=True,linestyle='none',markeredgewidth=5,elinewidth=5)
plt.errorbar(days2, fluxdensity2, yerr=0.01,uplims=True,linestyle='none',markeredgewidth=5,elinewidth=5)
plt.errorbar(days3, fluxdensity3, yerr=0.01,uplims=True,linestyle='none',markeredgewidth=5,elinewidth=5)
plt.errorbar(days4, fluxdensity4,yerr=0.01,uplims=True,linestyle='none',markeredgewidth=5,elinewidth=5)

plt.grid()



plt.xlabel('Days Since Explosion', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Flux Density muJy', fontsize=16)
plt.savefig('2014dtflux.pdf',format='pdf')
plt.xlim((9.9,10.1))
plt.ylim((-.03,.12))
plt.show()
```

[Full Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsqv2.png)

[Example of One Point Showing That The Tail of the Arrow is Pointing at (10,.0076)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31sfJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to draw an arrow. To draw an arrow in matplotlib, one may use a `FancyArrowPatch`.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

style="Simple,tail_width=2,head_width=5,head_length=7"
kw = dict(arrowstyle=style, color="k")

a1 = patches.FancyArrowPatch((0,0.7), (0,0.5),**kw )
a2 = patches.FancyArrowPatch((0,0.4), (0.0,0.3),**kw)


for a in [a1,a2]:
    plt.gca().add_patch(a)

plt.xlim(-1,1)

plt.show()
```